# Count the occurrences and print top K using C/STL

Tags: c++, stl, unordered-map

I have a large text file with tokens in each line. I want to count the number of occurrences of each token and sort this. How do I do that efficiently in C++ preferably using built-in functions and shortest coding (and, of course most efficient) ? I know how to do it in python, but not sure how to do it using unordered_map in STL.

Comment: @ildjarn As I mentioned I was able to count occurrences of tokens using unordered_map. Now I want to find top K efficiently and elegantly (short of implementing sort algorithm myself).

Comment: Show us the _code_ you tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd go with the unordered_map approach. For selecting the most frequent k tokens, assuming that k is smaller than the total number of tokens, you should take a look at [std::partial_sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sort).

By the way, `++frequency_map[token]` (where frequency_map is, say, `std::unordered_map<std::string, long>`) is perfectly acceptable in C++, although I think the equivalent in Python will blow up on newly seen tokens.

OK, here you go:

```
void most_frequent_k_tokens(istream& in, ostream& out, long k = 1) {
  using mapT = std::unordered_map<string, long>;
  using pairT = typename mapT::value_type;
  mapT freq;
  for (std::string token; in >> token; ) ++freq[token];
  std::vector<pairT*> tmp;
  for (auto& p : freq) tmp.push_back(&p);
  auto lim = tmp.begin() + std::min<long>(k, tmp.size());
  std::partial_sort(tmp.begin(), lim, tmp.end(),
      [](pairT* a, pairT* b)->bool {
        return a->second > b->second
               || (a->second == b->second && a->first < b->first);
        });
  for (auto it = tmp.begin(); it != lim; ++it)
    out << (*it)->second << ' ' << (*it)->first << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know how to read lines from a file in C++, this should be a push in the right direction

```
std::string token = "token read from file";
std::unordered_map<std::string,int> map_of_tokens;
map_of_tokens[token] = map_of_tokens[token] + 1;
```

You can then print them out in as such (for a test):

```
for ( auto i = map_of_tokens.begin(); i != map_of_tokens.end(); ++i ) {
    std::cout << i->first << " : " << i->second << "\n";
}
```